# Calling JavaScript functions in the onClick method

Tags: javascript, html

I have this function

```
    function setLang(ln){
    if(ln == "en"){
        window.location = "../../en/page/login.html";
    }else if(ln == "de"){
        window.location = "../../de/page/login.html";
    }else if(ln == "fr"){
        window.location = "../../fr/page/login.html";
    }
}
```

and call it inline like this

```
<img src="../../en/EN.png" class="flag" onclick="setLang('en')">
```

So this is where I want to access it from, from a `onclick` function.

I'm quite new to JS, So that's why I'm asking how can I do that.

Comment: Is this not working in some way?  It's not ideal to invoke JavaScript directly from the HTML markup, but it should work just fine.

Comment: What have you tried? If you are getting errors then you need to post those. If nothing seems to be working, then you should add some `window.alert`'s or `console.log`'s to debug where in your code you are getting. Errors can be viewed in your browser's console (generally f12 if in windows)

Comment: That looks good, what's the issue you are facing?

Comment: Where do you have that function defined? The best way to do it is to have a separate file `main.js` for your javascript code, and include it in your .html files with this line `<script src="/your/path/to/main.js"></script>`

Comment: Scrappedcola, I did not not try much, And where can I put the window.alert and console.log, and It simply does not like to work, Its not the function, Its the linking, I have tried a basic function with alert() and it did not work too.

Comment: Thanks @pablito.aven Im quite dumb.

Comment: You should check out some tutorials on debugging javascript, it will make your coding life easier and get you better help on SO. http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/javascript_debugging_for_beginners/

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="../../en/EN.png" class="flag" onclick="setLang('en')"/>
<script>
function setLang(ln){
if(ln == "en"){
    window.location = "../../en/page/login.html";
}else if(ln == "de"){
    window.location = "../../de/page/login.html";
}else if(ln == "fr"){
    window.location = "../../fr/page/login.html";
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Isn't this the same code as the one in the question?